# Follow example on R decision example

Tags: r, cart-analysis

I am looking at R decision trees and found this tutorial which is somewhat what i need, almost the exact thing i need.

So : http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-for-a-salary-negotiation-an-extension-of-decision-tree-models/

Could someone please guide me to how can i implement this project?
To be frank, i just copied and pasted the code into R and it gave me errors, like:

```
object 'xseq' not found
```

I'd appreciate your help very much!
Thank you!

Comment: There are errors in the code. You should contact the author to resolve them.

Comment: So, they are like, big errors?
I mean, like, i should start over because the code doesn't make sense?

Comment: @All the errors stem from the line `}     yseq <- payoff(xseq)   # plots` - there should either be a newline or a semi-colon after the `}`. As I said though, you should contact the author so he can correct the article.

Comment: You were right!!!!!!!!

Thank you, so so so much :)

Comment: If you want post it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors stem from the line:

```
  }     yseq <- payoff(xseq)   # plots
```

You should change this to:

```
  };     yseq <- payoff(xseq)   # plots
```

or

```
  }
 yseq <- payoff(xseq)   # plots
```